# Как ограничить двумерный массив?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно ограничить двумерный массив [8,6], но что-то нигде не нашел как это сделать.

В C# вот так:int[,] nums2 = new int[8, 6];.

Как это сделать в JS?

Comment: C# - это строготипизированный язык. В нем вы не сможете объявить массив не указав его размер, потому что под этот массив будет выделено вполне себе конкретный объем памяти. JavaScript  в свою очередь является слаботипизированным языком. В нем можно создать массив определенной емкости (`new Array(5)`) но это никак не будет вас ограничивать в возможности положить в данный массив более 5ти элементов

Comment: Вот это и огорчает, что можно положить более 5, ибо метод потом просто может поломаться, если что-то пойдет не так. Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как уже упомянул @МихаилРебров в комментариях, никто не запретит вам положить больше элементов в массив, чем его размер, объявленный изначально.

Однако вы можете своими силами ограничивать длину массива. Скажем, сделать проверку на наличие места в массиве при попытке положить туда новый элемент.

Вот простенький пример:

```js
const row = 8, column = 6;

let mass = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
  mass.push(new Array());
}

let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

let currentRow = 0, currentColumn = 0;

btn.onclick = (e) => {
  let elem = currentRow * column + currentColumn;
  if (currentColumn < column) { // если в ряде хватает места, положить в ряд
    mass[currentRow].push(elem);
    currentColumn++;
  } else if (currentRow + 1 < row) { // если в ряде не хватает места и следующий существует, положить в начало следующего 
    currentColumn = 0;
    currentRow++;
    mass[currentRow].push(elem);
    currentColumn++;
  } else { // в остальных случаях массив переполнен
    alert('Выход за пределы массива, прерываю попытку');
  }
  
  showMass(mass, row);
}


function showMass(mass, row) {
  let str='';
  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    str += mass[i].join(' ');
    str += '\n';
  }
  document.querySelector('.mass').innerText = str;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn"> положить в массив </div>

<div class="mass"> </div>
```